# Unable to use position:sticky; while adding element through .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, innerhtml

I want to make the menu stick to the top of the page.
The code works just fine if I just add the code to the page.
However, I want to use javascript because I want to be able to change the menu on every page without having to do it manually on each one.

```js
document.getElementById('menu-js').innerHTML = `<div id="menu">
 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Button_1</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="/src">Link 1</a>
    <a href="/src">Link 2</a>
    <a href="/src">Link 3</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Button_2</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="/src">Link 4</a>
   <a href="/src">Link 5</a>
   <a href="/src">Link 6</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>`
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Arsenal|Rubik&display=swap');
#menu {
  background-color: white;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -0.51%;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  margin: none;
  font-family: 'Arsenal';
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f2d3d8;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Arsenal';
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ffd3b6;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c06014;
  color: white;
}

#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

hr {
  margin-left: -20px;
  color: #c06014
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TITLE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='page-container'>
    <div id='content-wrap'>
      <h1>Content above menu</h1>
      <div id='menu-js'></div>
      <h1>body</h1>
      <h2>body</h2>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <hr>FOOTER</footer>
  </div>
  <script src='menu.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If possible, I would like to only use these three languages.
Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Olian04 I want to make my menu bar stick to the top of the page, but I havent been successful when I use JS (.innerHTML) to do so.
I have been able to do it by just pasting the code into where the `menu-js` div is, however. I don't want to add the raw code, since I would like to keep a source for  the menu, so i dont need to update each page individually if I change the menu

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems almost perfect in terms of sticky property. 
Try to add a `max-height` property(value in pixel) to the `menu-js` div.

Comment: sorry, but how would that help?
I tried using different values and it either did nothing, or (using small values) pushed some text under the menu bar

Comment: The menu div need to have some fixed height, because we are setting the "top: 0 & position: sticky". 
I have just inspect & added "max-height: 10px" to the menu-js so it worked.

For more details you can go through the link: 
https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46
At the end of the page it has an example which is also having some fixed height to the menu.

Comment: my code works fine in normal HTML. its adding the code using JS that breaks it